# DispatchKeyEvent: determine the exact type of the getCurrentFocus view

Tags: android

I have a custom activitygroup that adds and removes views to the stack.

I override the `dispatchKeyEvent` to check for certain keys pressed.

the problem is that I need to check the type of the current focused view like this:

```
View v=getCurrentFocus();
```

when I check for the type of the view,
it returns a type like this

```
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
```

what is this type and can I cast any class object to this type ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't just cast any class object to this type! Best practice is that you should only ever cast up the class hierarchy, or if you really must cast down make sure you check the type first using the instanceof operator.

Also, judging by the package name it's an internal android class, so you do not want any references to that in your code - if it's internal, it's non api. They could change it at any point and your app would immediately be broken.

Why are you checking the type of the view?
Are you looking for a particular type?
If so, it's be safer to do (for example):

```
View v = getCurrentFocus();
if(v instanceof SomeView){
//do stuff
}
```

Or if it is the decor view you are interested in use getDecorView instead of getCurrentFocus .

Comment: Thanks Kett, But I receive to types of views, A decor View and sometimes a normal textview or edittext, so I'm looking for a criteria to differentiate bewteen these

Comment: so what type of view do you care about?

Comment: I want to take a certain action if the view is DecorView

Comment: what about getDecorView instead of getCurrentFocus

Comment: was it getDecorView that solved your problem? If so I'll put it in the answer